# Accessing array of imageviews with for loop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am developing an app which has 9 image views in a 3x3 matrix.
I want to change their image if a user clicks them.
So tat requires linking 9 ids and 9 set on click listeners

Is it possible to access them using a for loop like this

```
public int[] imv= {R.id.im0, R.id.im1, R.id.im2, R.id.im3,R.id.im4, R.id.im5, R.id.im6, R.id.im7,R.id.im8};//Loading ids into array imv
for(int i=0;i<imv.length;i++)
        {
            ImageView im[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(imv[i]);//Attaching ids
        }
for(int i=0;i<imv.length;i++)
        {
            im[i].setOnClickListener
        }
```

I am getting an error with im[i]. But if I remove i I get an object im which is a collection of imageviews. How can I access the individual imageviews and set onclicklisteners?

Comment: You are doing well. What is the error. Have you init the *ImageView im[] = new ImageView[imv.length]* ?

Comment: Hi, I have init the im without i and got the object. But the problem is I am unable to access the individual imageviews. I want to know which tile is clicked in the 9 and change the tile image based on location. I able to get only im.setonclicklistener. How I can access the imageivews inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be better to go for GridView refer to this example

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

you can write your logic in getView method using imageView.setOnClickListener

Answer (score 0):

//scope of the im[i] will end in the first for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<imv.length;i++)
        {
            ImageView im[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(imv[i]);//Attaching ids
im[i].setOnClickListener(this);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that "im" is declared inside the for loop (making it local to the for loop only).. Declare "im" outside the loop, then just define it inside.

try:

```
ImageView im[] = new ImageView im[imv.length];
for(int i=0;i<imv.length;i++)
       {
           im[i] = (ImageView) findViewById(imv[i]);//Attaching ids
       }
```

Note: I've forgotten how to properly declare an array. Just confirm it elsewhere.. :D